# Compact set in a Hilbert Space

Tags: real-analysis, hilbert-spaces

I'm doing some exercises, but there is something in one of the questions I don't quite understand, so I'm really hoping someone might be able to clarify. The question is as follows:
Let $\mathcal H$ be a Hilbert Space with inner product $\lt\cdot,\cdot\gt$, and 
corresponding norm $\|\cdot\|$. Furthermore there is the set $B=\{x\in\mathcal H |\|x\|\le1\}$.

a) Show, that B is closed and bounded$^1$ regarding (the metric corresponding to) $\|x\|$.

b) Show, that if $\mathcal H$ doesn't have a finite dimension, then B isn't compact regarding (the metric corresponding to) $\|x\|$. (Hint: Look at a countable orthonormal system $\{e_n|n\in\mathbb N\}$ in $\mathcal H$.

c) Give an example of a Hilbert Space $\mathcal H$, where B isn't compact.

What I don't understand is, if I have to show in a) that B is compact, how can it suddenly be not-compact in b)? Where do we assume that $\mathcal H$ has a finite dimension in a)? And finally, in c) - haven't we just, in b) given an example - the example being all Hilbert Spaces which does not have a finite dimension?

$^1$ This is the same as being compact, right?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Closed and bounded does *not* imply compact - but compact implies closed and bounded. (I've made the same mistake many times.)

a) Of course if you could prove that $B$ is compact then you'd achieve this...but this claim is false!

b) So up to here is consistent. You don't assume $\mathcal{H}$ has finite dimension in $A$, since again closed and bounded is not the same as compact.

c) Sure, that's a valid example. Maybe you want to try considering the question for finite dimensions?

Comment: a) If B was always compact then you'd run into problems with compact operators, because the identity is never a compact operator.

Answer (score 0):

a) No, this is not in general true. For example, if you give $\mathbb{Z}$ the discrete metric, the whole space is closed and bounded but not compact. I think you can actually solve part a) by using the continuity of $\|\cdot\|$ and the fact that you're ball is the preimage of $[0,1]$.

b) You should try as hard as you can. If you need to, you can peek here [Is any closed ball non-compact in an infinite dimensional space?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/253081/is-any-closed-ball-non-compact-in-infinite-dimensional-space).

c) Yes, you are correct. Take your pick, $L^2$ for example.

Comment: @JonasMeyer You are of course correct--my head must have been elsewhere (I was thinking of Banach spaces).