# Compactness of translation operator in weighted spaces

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, operator-theory, compact-operators

Let $x,v\in\Bbb R^d$, $t\in \Bbb R$ and $m(x,v)$ be a smooth strictly positive function rapidly decaying on infinity - think $m(x,v) = \exp(-|x|^2-|v|^2)$.

Define Banach spaces $X$ and $Y$ by $$\|h(x,v)\|^2_X = \int_{\Bbb R^d\times\Bbb R^d}|h(x,v)|^2m(x,v)\,dx\,dv$$
$$
\|g(t,x,v)\|^2_Y = \sup_{t\in \Bbb R}\int_{\Bbb R^d\times\Bbb R^d}|g(t,x,v)|^2m(x-tv,v)\,dx\,dv.$$

Finally, we have a linear isometry $A:X\to Y$, $A[h](t,x,v) = h(x-tv,v)$.

I want to answer the question whether $A$ is compact or not. Most standard techniques apply only to operators in Hilbert spaces (in our case $Y$ is only a Banach space) and/or integral operators, so any hints/ideas/links will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: An isometry is never compact if the domain is infinite dimensional. Take any bounded sequence $(x_n)_n$ in the domain that has no convergent subsequence. If $A$ was compact, there would be a convergent subsequence $(A(x_{n_k}))_k$. Since $A$ is an isometry, this means that $(x_{n_k})_k$ is Cauchy, contradiction.

Comment: @PhoemueX, thank you! If you make your comment into an answer, I'll be able to upvote and accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A linear isometry defined on an infinite-dimensional space is **never** compact.

To see this, note that (as shown in this (somehow misformulated) question ([Is it true that the unit ball is compact in a normed linear space iff the space is finite-dimensional?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/287360/is-it-true-that-the-unit-ball-is-closed-in-a-normed-linear-space-iff-the-space-i))), a normed linear space is finite dimensional iff the closed unit ball is compact.

Thus, since your space $X$ is (obviously) not finite dimensional, there is a sequence $(x_n)_n$ in the unit ball of $X$ that has no convergent subsequence (and thus no Cauchy subsequence, since your space is complete).

If $A$ was a compact map, there would be a convergent (hence Cauchy) subsequence $(A x_{n_k})_k$. Since $A$ is a linear isometry, this easily implies that also $(x_{n_k})_k$ is Cauchy, in contradiction to the choice of $(x_n)_n$.

In particular, your map $A$ can not be compact.