# Normed space and finite dimensional space

Tags: general-topology, normed-spaces

i have this problem

let $E$ be a normed vector space and $A\subset E$ compact

How to prove that if $\overset{\circ}{A}\neq\emptyset$ then $dim E<\infty$

Answer (score 3):

This implies that the interior of $A$ contains a closed ball which is compact therefore the unit ball is compact, so the space is finite dimensional.

[Is it true that the unit ball is compact in a normed linear space iff the space is finite-dimensional?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/287360/is-it-true-that-the-unit-ball-is-compact-in-a-normed-linear-space-iff-the-space)

Comment: i don't understand how to prove, i think that i must start by: $\overset{\circ}{A}\neq\emptyset$ then there exists $x\in \overset{\circ}{A}$ it means there exist $r>0$ such that $x\in B(x,r)\subset A$ how to continue after that ?

Comment: Suppose that the adherence $\bar B(x,r)$ of $B(x,r)$ is compact, the map $h(u)=(u-x)/r$ is continue, this implies that $h(\bar B(x,r))=\bar B(0,1)$ is compact since the image of compact set by a continuous map is compact.

Comment: Why $\overline{B}(x,r)$ is compact ?is $\overline{B}(x,r)=B'(x,r)$ ????

Comment: because it is a closed subset of the compact set $A$.

Comment: but if $B\subset A$ and $B\subset \overline{B}$ this not imply that $\overline{B}\subset A$ ? but how we conclude ?????

Comment: If $B\subset A$ and $A$ is closed $\bar B\subset \bar A=A$ and here $A$ is closed since a compact set is closed.

Comment: ahh ok, so you define $h: \overline{B}(0,r)\rightarrow B'(0,1)$ and then $B'(0,1)$ is compact so $E$ is a finite dimensional space ?

Comment: ok,......... this is it

Comment: then we have equivalence between finite dimentional space and the unite closed ball is compact ???