# The smallest compact set that contains a bounded set in a metric space

Tags: metric-spaces, compactness

I came across the following assertion: Let $X$ be a metric space. Let $Y\subset X$ be a bounded set. Then, there exists a smallest compact set $K$ in $X$ such that $K\supset Y$.

How can I prove this? In $\mathbb{R}^n$, this looks trivial, because a compact set is equivalent to a closed and bounded set, so $K$ is just a closure of $Y$. But, in general metric space, I'm not sure how to prove this result.

Comment: What about $Y = X = (0, 1)$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Let $X$ be a metric space. Let $Y\subset X$ be a bounded set. Then, there exists a smallest compact set $K$ in $X$ such that $K\supset Y$.

This assertion is not true in general.

For an example, let $(V,||.||)$ be a normed vector space with dim$(V)$ $\geq \infty$. Note that the norm on the vector space induces a metric $d$ on the vector space as follows:

\begin{equation*}
d(u,v) = ||u-v|| \hspace{1cm} \forall u,v \in V
\end{equation*}

Let $B[0,1]$ denotes the close unit ball of $V$. i.e:

\begin{equation*}
B[0,1] = \{u \in V: ||u|| \leq 1\}
\end{equation*}

By definition it is a bounded set. If the assertion was true then there exists a smallest compact set $K$ in $V$ such that $B[0,1] \subset K$. But close subsets of compact set in a metric space is compact. So this forces $B[0,1]$ to be compact. But it is a well known fact that:

> The closed unit ball in a normed linear space is compact if and only if the vector space is finite dimensional.

You will get a discussion on this statement in this [link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/287360/is-it-true-that-the-unit-ball-is-compact-in-a-normed-linear-space-iff-the-space#:%7E:text=The%20unit%20ball%20is%20compact%20iff%20the%20space%20is%20finite,span%20of%20the%20previous%20vectors.). But we have taken $V$ to be infinite dimensional. So $B[0,1]$ is not compact. This is a contradiction.