# Proof Verification of Continuous Linear Maps are bounded

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, solution-verification, linear-transformations

This is what I am trying to prove:

Thrm: Let $T:X \to Y$ be a continuous linear map between normed spaces, then T is bounded.

Pf: By definition we have that $$ \left\lVert T \right\rVert = \sup_{ \left\lVert x\right\rVert  \leq 1 } \left\lVert Tx\right\rVert _Y  $$ , then put $f : X \to \mathbb{R}  $ where $f(x) = \left\lVert Tx\right\rVert _Y$   then as norms are continuous and $T$ is continuous then $f$ is the composition of continuous functions so we have that $f$ is continuous. Therefore, because the set of $x \in X$   such that $ \left\lVert x\right\rVert  \leq 1 $  is compact we have that  we have that $\sup_{ \left\lVert x\right\rVert  \leq 1} f(x) < \infty $ by the extreme value theorem, hence we conclude that $\left\lVert T \right\rVert  < \infty $ $\square$

Something feels off, it feels a little too simple, I guess i just want to double check that I am not missing anything.

Thank you!

Comment: The unit ball is compact iff the space $X$ is finite dimensional. See [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/287360/is-it-true-that-the-unit-ball-is-compact-in-a-normed-linear-space-iff-the-space). Hence your proof is incomplete.

Comment: I had a feeling something was going on with the compactness, feel free to write this as an answer I will accept it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My favorite way is to argue by contradiction, although $\varepsilon$-$\delta$ argument with $\varepsilon=1$ is simple as well. Assume $T$ is not bounded. Then $$\sup_{\|x\|\le 1}\|Tx\|=\infty$$ Therefore for every $ n$ there exists $x_n$ such that $\|x_n\|\le 1 $ and $\|Tx_n\|\ge n^2.$ Hence $y_n:={x_n\over n}\to 0$ and $\|Ty_n\|\ge n.$ Thus $T$ is not continuous at $0.
$

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

Write down some kind of epsilon-delta definition for the continuity of $T$ at the origin. Use linearity of $T$ to simplify what's going on.

As commented, you cannot use the extreme value principle since the unit ball isn't compact in general.

Comment: Thank you! I did see that proof!