# If the unit ball of a normed space is compact, the space is finite dimensional, without AC

Tags: normed-spaces, axiom-of-choice

Let $X$ be a normed space, $E:=\{x\in X: \|x\| \leq 1\}.$

The definition of “compact” is the usual one by finite subcover (i.e., not by Dedekind-finite subcover, ultrafilters converge, etc.).

**Theorem**
If $E$ is compact, then $X$ is finite dimensional.

**Proof**([source](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/287368/1164202))

> prove the contrapositive by fixing $\epsilon > 0$ and then choosing a countable set of linearly independent vectors with length less than $1$, so that each subsequent vector is further than $\epsilon$ from the span of the previous vectors. This can be done with [Riesz's lemma](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riesz%27s_lemma). This is a sequence with no convergent subsequence.

**Question**

I think the above proof uses the axiom of dependent choice. Is there a proof of this theorem that uses neither AC nor a weaker version of it?

Comment: Define "compact" in this case. Just the usual finite subcover? Dedekind-finite subcover? Ultrafilters converge? Etc.

Comment: @AsafKaragila Just the usual finite subcover. I don’t know other definitions.